# Error counting substrings from file in Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, counter, fortran95, substring

I'm trying to write a code in Fortran 95 that read strings from a file and then print a frequency table of letters from the file. The file has a text like the example below, with no more than 128 characters per line:

```
Ablblb lbla sdrtwfwefw
Waerfaw efeafawef awef
Pefwae fwefawefw efawe
Fcicnj ioejo, o njcdid
Pweko jai, wadwed awdd
```

So I did one program that is working fine for the first letter (A or a), but the counter doesn't work for the rest of the letters and always print "0". This is what I did:

```
    program read_file
      implicit none
      integer :: count, i, j, k, n
      character(len=80) :: arch
      character(len=128) :: line
      character :: c, d
      logical :: rexist

      print *,'Name of the file (example: "text1.txt"): '
      read *,arch

      count=0

      inquire(file=arch, exist=rexist)
        if(rexist) then
          open(unit=10, file=arch)
          j=97
          do i=65,90
            c=achar(i)
            d=achar(j)
            do
              read(unit=10, fmt='(A128)', end=999)line
              n=len_trim(line)
              do k=1,n
                if(line(k:k)==c .or. line(k:k)==d)then
                count=count+1
                end if
              end do
              cycle
              999 exit
            end do
            print *, "Letter ", c, " or ", d, " Total: ", count
            j=j+1
            count=0
          end do
          close(unit=10)
        else
          print *,"Invalid file!"
        end if

    end program read_file
```

The first `count` works fine (letter A or a) but it prints "0" for the rest of the letters. Is there something wrong with the DO loop that doesn't reset the variable `count` properly?

Comment: You may find it helpful to look at when the file end is reached.

Comment: I guess there is a really obvious mistake that i'm still not seeing.

Comment: I haven't time to answer properly, but see that you're reading the entire file in the first `i` iteration.  You either need to rewind the file for the second iteration or, better, change the loop ordering.

Comment: The REWIND statement! That solved the problem. I'll see what I can do to change the loop order, but at least it's working now. Thank you! :)